# how to dynamically get all nested properties from JSON Array object in Azure KQL

Tags: json, azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-resource-graph

I am trying to get all data disks present on VM from Azure Resource Graph Query. I am able to get specific data disk by specifying the index( for example properties.storageProfile.dataDisks[0].name for first disk) but but how do I get this dynamically as some has more than 1 data disks. if VM has 3 disks, is it possible to get details and put it in new column with value as "disk1,disk2,disk3,etc". Using below I am able to extract first disk.

```
  resources
| where ['type'] == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| extend DataDiskName = properties.storageProfile.dataDisks[0].name
| extend DataDiskSizeGB = properties.storageProfile.dataDisks[0].diskSizeGB
| extend DataDiskSizeType = properties.storageProfile.dataDisks[0].managedDisk.storageAccountType
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let resources = datatable(id:int,type:string,properties:dynamic)
[
    1 ,'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines', dynamic({"storageProfile":{"dataDisks":[{"name":"dd11","diskSizeGB":11,"managedDisk":{"storageAccountType":"sat11"}}]}})
   ,2 ,'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines', dynamic({"storageProfile":{"dataDisks":[{"name":"dd21","diskSizeGB":21,"managedDisk":{"storageAccountType":"sat21"}},{"name":"dd22","diskSizeGB":22,"managedDisk":{"storageAccountType":"sat22"}},{"name":"dd23","diskSizeGB":23,"managedDisk":{"storageAccountType":"sat23"}}]}})
   ,3 ,'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines', dynamic({"storageProfile":{"dataDisks":[{"name":"dd31","diskSizeGB":31,"managedDisk":{"storageAccountType":"sat31"}},{"name":"dd32","diskSizeGB":32,"managedDisk":{"storageAccountType":"sat32"}}]}})
];
resources
| where ['type'] == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| mv-apply with_itemindex=i dd = properties.storageProfile.dataDisks on (summarize properties = make_bag(pack(strcat(i+1,"_name"),dd.name, strcat(i+1,"_diskSizeGB"),dd.diskSizeGB, strcat(i+1,"_storageAccountType"),dd.managedDisk.storageAccountType)))
| evaluate bag_unpack(properties)
```

[image]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA7WTMW/CMBCFd36F5YVEdVMl3lIxtKrUtVK7IYRMfIBFbEe2A6U0/70XRCGkHbIQL7F97/ndJ10JgTjwtnYFeDIhUgRcixIiJXNlAgv7CnIfnDIrVjlbgQsKfC73RmhVxKPpiOCXEjbGrbPeLkNSWF3VAR62yoValFoUa2XAjxk5yaID9cE6sYI3Z5eqBJofaPv0i/IbT/PpgWIdnlIp05QyKvH8XX3B6zPN05RRLQyKZVveSk9mT0VhaxM%20MDJKvQiobZpZ08RtSJbdLmTWD5kND5m1IVnXLOubZcPNsr4Z75vx4Wa8i4/fDh/v4%20PD8fE%20Pt7Hx4fj49lvx7PH0XkuRt9ktwYHZDpux2E8I5MJGcACdXp7L6qq3JOdCuu5CqCVkfA5UURKHLfLRCXXsJIzKWINiXyttXDYT0eBci02MF%20IVVSJYhPhlBYiROoO4c2POGImZdL%20MXJ12aFzLLnse4X/cDoKOjiTvzVxHGPrsBVlLQIQDDivzTHiJX38A4L8q3N6BAAA)

Comment: I  get an error (invalid query) when I run the same Query in Azure Resource Graph explorer and same query works fine in Log analytics workspace

Comment: Azure Resource Graph seems to support just a subset of KQL